# Submit Account address SObject Tree for the API rest

Tags: javascript

I am trying to submit Account address using javascript by SObject Tree, I am not sure what I am doing wrong for account address object
here is the object

```
   var accountInfo = { "records": [{
   "attributes": { "type": "Account", "referenceId": "acc1" },
   "name": $( "input[id*='name']" ).val(),
   "brand__c":"xbp",
   address: {
       "records": [{
   "line1": $( "input[id*='pqStreet']" ).val(),
   "line2": { type: $("select[id*='unType']").val(), value: $("input[id*='unValue']").val()},
 "city": $( "input[id*='pqCity']" ).val(), 
 "state": $( "[id*='pqState'] option:selected" ).val(), 
 "postalCode": $( "input[id*='pqZip']" ).val(),
    }]},
   "Contacts": {
     "records": [{
       "attributes": { "type": "Contact", "referenceId": "con1" },
       "firstname": "John",
       "lastname": "Doe"
     }]
   },
   "Opportunities": {
     "records": [{
       "attributes": { "type": "Opportunity", "referenceId": "opp1" },
       "name": "Closing Soon",
       "closedate": "2018-09-01",
       "stagename": "Prospecting"
     }]
   }
 }]
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to define the address as if it were a "child" record (you have the "child relationship name" followed by an array of "records"). Instead, you should refer to the fields as their proper API names:

```
"billingstreet": $( "input[id*='pqStreet']" ).val()+'\n'+ 
                 $("select[id*='unValue']").val(),
"billingcity": $( "input[id*='pqCity']" ).val(),
"billingstate": $( "[id*='pqState'] option:selected" ).val(), 
"billingpostalcode": $( "input[id*='pqZip']" ).val(),
```

I'm not sure I've understood the intent of how you have the billing street laid out, so you'll need to tweak the code accordingly.

Comment: is the shipping address  same thing?

Comment: @Metawaa It's a different set of fields. It really depends on the purpose. Billing is typically where bills are sent, shipping is where stuff is shipped to. Most places use the same address for both, but it may not necessarily be so. Use whichever your organization expects the data to be in.